# Extract text into a new column using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to script out a hotfix reporting automation system. My first attempt was using `Get-Hotfix` but it only reports the KB article number and doesn't have a description of the update.

I read about this, but it doesn't have the KB article number in it's own column.

My script is as follows:

```bsh
Get-WmiObject -cl Win32_ReliabilityRecords | 
    select @{LABEL = "date";EXPRESSION = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated)}},
        @{LABEL = "KBArticle"; EXPRESSION = {(-match[regex]::'\(([^\ []*)\)/g').groups[1].value($_.productname)}},
        pscomputername, productname
```

When I run it, the KBArticle column is blank.

I tried a test for one line and it works. Found it on another Stack Overflow post.

```bsh
$productname = "Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB3118401)"
$r = [regex] "\(([^\[]*)\)"
$match = $r.Match("$productname")
$text = $match.Groups[1].Value
```

I've also tried the regex in some of the online regex testers and it extracts the text I want. My problem is that I can't get it to work in my script.

Comment: The vast majority of the instances on my machine do not look like that pattern at all

Comment: In your one line test you use `$r.match()` method - in the script the `-match operator` with an expression I doubt is correct (see get-help about_Comparison_Operators) - but even if it worked my current `get-wmiobject -cl win32_reliabilityRecords` output doesn't show any output that would be matched.

Comment: I ran `win32_reliabilityRecords` and it does not show KB numbers (reliably) . You may want to take another route. When you say you want a description with the KB number? If you want a basic description (Update / Security Update) you could use `Win32_QuickFixEngineering`

Comment: We wanted a somewhat detailed description  like Reliability Records provides. I think MS had a database of KB articles somewhere and in theory I could join the results of get-hotfix to it to get more data, but wanted to avoid it if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below does extract the ones you want. But you might need to look your regex after. It will only extract the KB articles(and other stuff with parenthesis around them) with parenthesis around them.
I also removed "/g" from your first regex.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_reliabilityRecords | Select-Object `
@{LABEL = "date"; EXPRESSION = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.timegenerated)}}, `
@{LABEL = "KBArticle"; EXPRESSION = {[regex]::Match($_.productname, '\(([^\ []*)\)').captures.groups[1].value}}, `
    pscomputername, productname
```

Some reading about regex, powershell and groups 
https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/30/regex-groups-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. If any issues come up I can probably handle them.